# "Hashing" Algorithm Implementation

Tags: arrays, c

I am given an input consisting of 2 parts, the first line consists of 2 numbers denoting the size of a matrix, `N` and `M`, followed by the matrix itself, `A`. The maximum size of the matrix is `1 <= N, M <= 100`, and each of the elements of the matrix is `0 <= A[i][j] <= pow(10, 9)`. The "hash" is calculated by adding the elements in each column, and multiplying all the sums, modulo 1000000007 (`pow(10, 9) + 7`).

My code is as follows:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int rows, cols;
    scanf("%d %d", &rows, &cols); getchar();

    unsigned long long int data[rows][cols];
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
            scanf("%llu", &data[row][col]);
        }
        getchar();
    }

    unsigned long long int coltot[cols];
    for(int i=0;i<cols;i++){coltot[i]=0;}
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
            coltot[col] += data[row][col];
        }
    }

    unsigned long long int colmult, colmulttemp = (coltot[0] % 1000000007);
    for (int i = 1; i < cols; i++) {
        colmulttemp *= coltot[i];
        colmulttemp %= 1000000007;
    }
    colmult = colmulttemp;

    printf("%llu\n", colmult);

    return 0;
}
```

However, upon submission, the results I got indicated that some test cases were failing. The question only gave the following test cases:

```
stdin:
2 2
1 5
1 5
stdout:
20

stdin:
3 3
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
stdout:
2160
```

which my code passses correctly. I did however, go out of my way to attempt to input the maximum values. I wrote a program to print `1000000000` 100 times horizontally and 100 times vertically into a text file. However, upon directing the file in, I got a bus error:

```
$ ./main < data.txt
Bus error (core dumped)
$
```

Could this be the reason some test cases are failing? Or is the problem elsewhere? Regardless, how would I fix it?

Thank you for your time.

---

Update: I have found the problem with the bus derror: I forgot to specify the matrix's size when I generated the matrix. It now works, but I found it generates a different result compared to a python3 program, with the C program returning `213129341`, whereas the python3 program returned `991047043`.

```
>>> import math
>>> x = pow(10, 9)
>>> xx = x * 100
>>> m = x + 7
>>> r = x
>>> i = 1
>>> while(i < 100):
...     i += 1
...     r = r * xx
...     r = r % m
...
>>> r
991047043
>>> r % m
991047043
>>>
```

This still doesn't bring me any closer to figuring out why my code is incorrect, unfortunately. Any ideas?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Where was the error when you opened the core file in the debugger?

Comment: What are you using `getchar();` for? All numeric conversion specifiers ignore leading whitespace. If there is a non-whtespace character anywhere but the last in line, `getchar()` won't help anyway.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin It consumes the newline that remains after every press of the enter key. I have developed a habit to keep it there anyway, since it affects `scanf()` in some circumstances.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I don't have a debugger, I simply ran the executable in a terminal, which spat the error to `stdout`. I use clang to compile in the terminal, if it matters.

Comment: Seems like a good time to learn to use one.

Comment: I found the problem: I forgot to specify the matrix's size. It all works now. However, it still gives a different result: the c program gave `213129341`, whereas a test I did in python3 gave me `326857314`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overflow is possible when multiplying the sums.

Denote the maximal element in the matrix by M (here M = 1000000000, which is approximately 2<sup>30</sup>). M is also approximately equal to your modulo-number. If the matrix is NxN, the sum over a row or column is bounded by M*N. The initialization value for `colmulttemp` is bounded by M. When multiplying these numbers, we get M<sup>2</sup>*N as an intermediate result. For M=10<sup>9</sup> and N=10<sup>2</sup>, this is 10<sup>20</sup>, which overflows 64-bit numbers.

Fortunately, there is a simple fix - just do your modulo reduction to all your sums, and not only to the first one. Then your intermediate result is bounded by M<sup>2</sup>, which is just below 2<sup>64</sup>. BTW this is the reason for this particular value of M - it's large enough to make all your numbers impressively big, and small enough to fit intermediate results into 64-bit integers.

```
for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
    coltot[col] %= 1000000007;
}

unsigned long long int colmult,
    colmulttemp = coltot[0]; // % 1000000007 not necessary here
```

Comment: Ah, indeed it is the problem. I forgot to consider the additions as well. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

> Could this be the reason some test cases are failing?

Yes.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Why would this be, and what could I do to remedy it?

Comment: @404NameNotFound sorry for the short answer, but the question you had is legitimate and that's the correct answer. It's hard to elaborate more, but anything that causes your code to crash can cause test cases to fail because, well, they could crash too.